# How to find tomcat Current thread busy programatically

Tags: tomcat, tomcat6

I can see this details under Tomcat  ://hostname:port/manager/status

Max threads: 150 Min spare threads: 25 Max spare threads: 75 Current thread count: 25 Current thread busy: 4

Now my question is i need to find the **Current thread busy count** using my code. since i need to intimate the user when this count reaches 200.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using JMX. First, connect to your own Tomcat process using `jconsole` and poke-around under the "Catalina" tree. Each `<Executor>` (or `<Connector>` in older versions of Tomcat) has a JMX bean that exposes its current status, including what the active/spare/max thread counts are.

Or, you could just look at the source code to the manager webapp to see how it works: that's one of the wonderful features of Open-Source Software.

Comment: I needed to do this things pragmatically..For ex: for my project i need to read the tomcat  "Current thread busy count" from java or javascript

Comment: You *do* know that you can access JMX programmatically, right? Do you need the thread count in the *client* or the *server*?

Comment: I need to read to access JMX programmatically..since i have not used yet. i am working on it. Please share ur knowledge if u can that wound be help me lot.

Comment: You can read JMB beans from within the process or remotely. You can write code to inspect the JMX beans and run it wherever you want. If you want a JMX tutorial, search the Internet for one. Or, you could look at Tomcat's source code: I can recommend looking at the JMXProxyServlet's source code, since it does basically exactly what you want.

Comment: I also want to read the `current thread busy` number from Java Code running within the same JVM as Tomcat. So why is nowhere an example for this? I didn't achieve it, should be easy, no? Within the same JVM there is no need for remote calls etc...

Comment: I've said it before and I'll say it again: read the source code to Tomcat's `JMXProxyServlet`. It is itself an example of *exactly what you are trying to do*.